# Android - adding Twitter handle to phonebook

Tags: android, contactscontract

I am trying to add a Twitter handle to a contact using the [ContactsContrtact API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html), but I can't seem to figure out how to add a custom protocol to my `Intent`. Has anyone done something like this?

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT,
                             Uri.parse("mailto: user@example.com"));
Intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.IM_HANDLE, "username");
Intent.putExtra(ContractsContact.Intents.Insert.IM_PROTOCOL, "twitter");
startActivity(intent);
```

This does not work probably because the `Intent` extras are not associated with one another? I was looking into something along the line of using the ContentProviderOperation like this code [snippet](http://matrix-examplecode.blogspot.com/2012/03/add-contact-details-in-android.html).